Cannot upload pickle object containing list of sparse matrices. I get ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scipy.sparse._arrays'
import pickle

from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix

When I try to open Pickle file containing a list of sparsematrices that I have used numerous times before without any issue, I get the following error:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scipy.sparse._arrays'
I haven't been able to find this exact error anywhere online.
I am using Jupyter notebook via Anaconda on Windows.
This problem happens with both 1.12.0 and 1.13.0 (latest) versions of Scipy package.
I have uninstalled and installed the package multiples times, but still the issue persists.

What version of SciPy did you create the pickle in? This matters due to the fact that pickle is not necessarily portable across versions: https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/202006/pickles_nine_flaws.html#h_old_pickles_look_like_old_code

scipy.sparse._arrays.py is present in version 1.10, I don't find it in the online docs for 1.13.  Looks like there's been some reorganization of the sparse package.  Formats like csr_array are a relatively new addition, and should be considered experiemental.

You won't find errors like this 'online' if no one else has encountered it or talked about it.  And that is possible if your error is the result of saveing the matrix with 1.10, and you now have 1.12.  Details of why this happens depends on how files were reorgansized, and what the original pickle saved.  The sparse.save_npz format might handle version differences better since it just uses the numpy.savez mechanism.

Ok so, OP here. I posted this on SciPy library main repository on Github and the folks there resolved this issue. Please go here.
The problem was—as one person commented here—that the pickle file was made in an earlier version of the library and that The module scipy.sparse._arrays was removed in 1.11.0.
I am short on time so I simply downgraded my scipy version to 1.10.0 and voila! It worked.
To downgrade, in anaconda prompt, do:
pip uninstall scipy
pip install scipy==1.10.0
Confirm by:
pip freeze
In the list generated, look for scipy. Next to it, its version would be written.
